# Filter coffee machine vs boiling on the stove

Tags: brewing-process, filter

I just saw you can buy a coffee machine that uses a rather simple filter method to brew coffee.
[Exhibit A](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/appliances/coffee-maker-reviews/a45465/keurig-k-compact/)

I wondered what is the difference between that machine and brewing coffee in a pot on the stove.
Unfortunately I'm not well-versed enough in English coffee terms to get meaningful Internet search results.

Comment: I think the terms you might be looking for in regards to stove-top brewers will probably be moka pot or percolator.

Comment: @Shiri, bless you!

Comment: If you actually LIKE coffee that is boiled in a pot on the stove, go right ahead. suit yourself. Most people find it terrible, which is why other techniques exist. You appear to have some inbuilt bias against normal brewing methods - if you get results YOU like, that's fine for you. I'll avoid having "coffee" at your house, though. I see from one of your other questions that you don't even drink coffee - you find it terrible - perhaps this has to do with your resistance to normal methods?

Comment: @Ecnerwal, but brewing on the stove *are* the normal brewing methods? At least to me. Long story - short I will be buying a new coffee maker thingy and am gathering information in order to decide if I should buy a moka pot, percolator or Exhibit A. Never had a thing like Exhibit A, so everyone I know drinks from a moka pot or some coffee thing-a-magik

Comment: Ahem! If you mean decoction based techniques, which is mostly Turkish coffee, _boiling on the stove_ and _brewing on the stove_ are really too apart from each other. Just to note.

Comment: @mtsan, o-o-oh, shiny! The world of coffee is interesting, indeed. :)

Comment: @mathgenius I would strongly suggest you investigate the French Press method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_press - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Gns9HtHc5w

Answer (score -3):

The main difference between both the stovetop and French Press is brew time. Stovetop takes less time to brew and French Press longest brew time, thus making the coffee taste better. :)

Comment: A longer brew time does not mean better coffee, that's just wrong.